# PHP Path Variable Doubling Up

Tags: php

In my code I am defining a path variable:

```
define('IMG_PATH', 'localhost/testsite/images');
```

Then using it to access images in my html:

```
<img src="<?php echo IMG_PATH; ?>/website-logo.png" height="75">
```

But when loading the page it is rendering like this:

```
localhost/testsite/localhost/testsite/image/website-logo.png
```

Why is localhost/testsite doubling up?  Any thoughts?  I've tested in both locally and online, the domain is doubling up in both environments.

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Try `define('IMG_PATH', 'http://localhost/testsite/images');`, otherwise your browser will believe it's a relative URL and prepend the current absolute path.

Comment: Bingo!  That was it!  Thanks!

Comment: Btw `define('IMG_PATH', '/testsite/images');` should also work and not be domain-dependent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `/` before file path/ page url and don't add domain name it should be independent

```
define('IMG_PATH', '/testsite/images')
```

Answer (score 0):

You will define path like that for all project.

```
define('IMG_PATH', '/testsite/images');
```